# Best way to create composite primary key on a huge table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, composite-primary-key

I have a huge table of about 31GB data and close to 150k records. Currently this table is created without primary key to speed up the insert process as I have to copy the data from a live database.

I have to create a composite primary key on this table on 3 columns (int, varchar, varchar)

I am thinking of doing like below

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD PRIMARY KEY(col1, col2, col3);
```

Please suggest me there is any better way to do this

Comment: How is a table with so few rows, so physically vast? Are you storing BLOB data?

Comment: Yes, I have 1 blob column in the table

Comment: If you need a key over these 3 columns there is no other/better way to create the key than the specified syntax.

Comment: Your blobs average 200k. Just to observe, that for files larger than 100k, it's more efficient (in my limited experience) to store these in a file server.

Comment: Thanks IOV GELOV. Just curious, given the size and no. of rows in the table, can you provide me an approximate time to get this query executed

Comment: Yes Strawberry, I am aware of that. But we don't have a choice of saving this data in file server now :(